# How to fix the error argument of type string or undefined is not assignable to parameter of type string using typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am getting error argument of type string or undefined is not assignable to parameter of type string using typescript and react

below is my code,

```js
    function List({items}: Props) { 
        const [activeindex, setActiveindex] = React.useState<string>();
        return (
            items.map((item: any) => {
                <AddButton setActiveIndex={setActiveIndex} itemId={item.id}/>
            }
        );
    }

    
    interface AddButtonProps {
        setActiveIndex: any;
        itemId?: string;
    }
    function AddButton ({setActiveIndex, itemId}: AddButtonProps){
        const {toggleDrawing} = useDrawing();
        const handleClick = (itemId) => {
            setActiveIndex(itemId);
            toggleDrawing(itemId); //error here
        }
        return (
            <Button onClick={handleClick}/>
        );
    );


    function useDrawing () {
        const [editableItemId, setEditableItemId] = React.useState<string>();
        const toggleDrawing = React.useCallback(async (itemId: string) => {
            if (isDrawing && editableItemId === itemId) {
                cancelDrawing();
            } else if (isDrawing) {
                cancelDrawing();
                setEditableItemId(itemId);
            } else {
                setEditableWorkAreaId(itemId);
            }
        },
            [isDrawingPolygon, editableItemId, cancelDrawing]
    );
}
```

I am not sure why i am getting this error. could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You interface defines `itemId?: string;` and a string or undefined but the function call needs a string.

Use either

```
if (itemId) {
  toggleDrawing(itemId);
}
```

or

`toggleDrawing(itemId || '');`

or

`toggleDrawing(itemId as string);`

Answer (score 1):

try this way ;)

```
const toggleDrawing = React.useCallback(async (itemId: string | undefined) => {
    if (isDrawing && editableItemId === itemId) {
        cancelDrawing();
    } else if (isDrawing) {
        cancelDrawing();
        setEditableItemId(itemId);
    } else {
        setEditableWorkAreaId(itemId);
    }
   },[])
```

Comment: @Adrian Brand u may need check again, I just finish my answer just now

Comment: It is the AddButton function that is failing